# Scikit Learn Logistic Regression Memory Leak

Tags: efficiency, performance, scikit-learn

I'm curious if anyone else has run into this. I have a data set with about 350k samples, each with 4k sparse features. The sparse fill rate is about 0.5%. The data is stored in a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` object, with `dtype='numpy.float64'`.

I'm using this as an input to sklearn's Logistic Regression classifier. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) indicates that sparse CSR matrices are acceptable inputs to this classifier. However, when I train the classifier, I get extremely bad memory performance; the memory usage of my process explodes from ~150 MB to fill all the available memory and then everything grinds to a halt as memory swapping to disk takes over.

Does anyone know why this classifier might expand the sparse matrix to a dense matrix? I'm using the default parameters for the classifier at the moment, within an updated anacoda distribution. Thanks!

```
scipy.__version__ = '0.14.0'
sklearn.__version__ = '0.15.2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this ended up being an RTFM situation, although in this case it was RTF error message.

While running this, I kept getting the following error:

```
DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
```

I assumed that, since this had to do with the target vector, and since it was a warning only, that it would just silently change my target vector to 1-D.

However, when I explicitly converted my target vector to 1-D, my memory problems went away. Apparently having the target vector in an incorrect form caused it to convert my input vectors into dense vectors from sparse vectors.

Lesson learned: **follow the recommendations** when sklearn 'suggests' you do something.